# Error with Ionic App: execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I checked all the posts speaking about this error:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

But none of them match exactly my case here and none of them answered/solved my issue... I'm tired of searching (about 12 hours and haven't find anything...)

## Explaination

I'm using Ionic (last version) to build an app. My first issue was about the `SenderID` problem: cannot put it in the init function, but when I removed it, it wasn't working on Android... And when I put it, it said that it is not assignable to `PushOptions`, you see the trick.

## Actual error

The actual error that I have is the following:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/BuildHelper.class

Here what I've done to be here:

### Steps

So I decided to switch to `cordova-plugin-fcm` as I see at different places that it is easy to configure it. Jump through it, generate all the necessary files (`google-services.json` etc...) install and run all the TS that the plugin need: no TS errors.

My problem: when I run `ionic cordova run android` - or just a build, it's the same - I had multiples issues:

#### First error

First I had an issue about play-services that is unknown so it will jump through version 9.0.0: I solved it by using `cordova-plugin-firebase` instead and `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release`.

#### Second Error

Secondly I had this one:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/cordova/PermissionHelper.class

That I resolved using:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2
```

But now, I'm stuck with the "Actual error" and no way to build my app.

### Stack

Cordova plugins:

```
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 1.1.3 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.24 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-multidex 0.1.2 "Cordova Multi Dex"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: Did you already remove and readd the `platforms` and `plugins` folders?

Comment: Platforms yes, plugins not. I will try this morning ! Thx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what I did to get rid of this problem:

- Remove your platforms:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

- Remove the following directories in your app:

```
\platforms
\plugins
```

- re-add your platforms:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova platform add android
```

After that you can re-build the app and it should work

Comment: Yeah, you rock dude. It's working ! Can't believe it's "just" that ! Thank you.

Comment: Making this made the building process fail.
I have now this message just after the display of JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME:
"The specified path was not found".
@Daniel do you know what is causing this ?

Comment: It appears that the value of either of those environment variables does not point to a valid directory in your system